# Meteor geo location from browser package

Tags: meteor

I've tried searching atmosphere and the web for any package to get users Geo location (latitude, longitude) while accessing the app using their desktop browsers but couldn't find any. Existing applications serve mobile only ex. [MDG Geo Location](https://atmospherejs.com/mdg/geolocation)  Can someone please tell me how to get the user geo location (latitude, longitude) from desktop through Meteor? Thanks

Comment: Regular Javascript `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` should work just fine.  Have you tried it?

Comment: You could read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: There's already a nice package from Meteor development group, [mdg:geolocation](https://atmospherejs.com/mdg/geolocation).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, however, thought of putting this through.

You can try using the [gunjansoni:html5-api](https://atmospherejs.com/gunjansoni/notifications) package. It has geo location and lot of other HTML5 Apis to play with.

After you install the package on you client

```
var html5api = new Html5Api();
```

and then request for geo location permissions:

```
var geoLocation = html5api.geoLocation();
```

Once you have the permissions, get the location.

```
if (geoLocation) {
    geoLocation.getLocation(function(err, res){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(res);
    });
}
```

The result will be something like this:

```
{
    accuracy: 30 // in meters
    altitude: null
    altitudeAccuracy: null
    heading: null
    latitude: <latitude>
    longitude: <longitude>
    speed: null
    timestamp: 1457901207220
}
```

Or you can watch a user's location

```
if (geoLocation) {
    geoLocation.watch(function (err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            // the result will be in res.result
            console.log(res.result);
            Meteor.setInterval(function () {
                // to stop watching a location, you need a watchId which is available in res.watchId when the watch started
                geoLocation.stopWatching(res.watchId);
            }, 30 * 1000);
        }
    });
}
```